# Dynamically created proxy URL using Node/Express

Tags: node.js, express, proxy

I want to use express to create unique proxy instances using URLs that I am storing in a database. I found an npm module that may help with this called **http-express-proxy** but open to other solutions that uses **express**.

And I had a route like this (using http-express-proxy):

```
user.URL = 'https://www.google.com'

app.post('/', proxy(user.URL))

// and after this, user.URL is updated to a different value. I want the proxy's address to change too.
```

I did find a solution that dynamically creates a regular express route during runtime, but I cannot get it to work using the proxy() method from **http-express-proxy**:

https://alexanderzeitler.com/articles/expressjs-dynamic-runtime-routing/

According to that approach, I can require a 2nd file inside the POST route that looks like this: (and includes a call to the database using **sequelize**)

```
const express = require('express')
const proxy = require('express-http-proxy')

const User = require('../db/models/user')

const app = express()

module.exports= {
    init : init
}
function init(app) {
    User.findOne({where: {id: 1}})
        .then(user => app.post('/', proxy(user.URL)))   
}
```

And in my main app.js file, I am then doing this:

```
// ...

app.post('/', function(req, res, next) { 
    var dynamic = require('./dynamic')
    dynamic.init(app)
})

// ...
```

But I am getting a 503 response when I post using this approach using **http-express-proxy**, which was not used in his example.

Comment: This may sound ridiculous, but it's not because your data example has lowercase `url` and the code has `user.URL`? What does `user.URL` come out with if you console.log it, and the same for the result of the function `proxy(user.URL)`?

Comment: Yes @MattFletcher, my data structure was inconsistent. It was not actual code but meant as an example. I'll update this now.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work like this. I modified the express-http-proxy module and at the top of the SendProxyRequest() method I included this:

```
if (req.URL) host = req.URL
```

And then in my app.js file I added a middleware method to set req.URL after a call to the database:

```
function getProxyURL (req, res, next) {
    User.findOne({where: {id: 1}})
        .then(user => {
            if(user.URL) req.URL = user.URL
            next()
        })
}

app.post('/', getProxyURL, proxy('www.default.com'))
```

Comment: To mark this as your preferred answer, please click the tick mark adjacent, when the system allows you to. Thanks.

Comment: This answer doesn't work anymore, producing `TypeError: Cannot read property 'URL' of undefined`